# Mystery Snail laid eggs in a terrible location-, hatchling health help

Tags: health, aquarium, snails, eggs, reproduction

I recently put two of my mystery snails together (originally separated between 2 tanks). They spent almost an entire day together "piggy backing" each other. Woke up and feed my fish this morning and found an egg sac on my filter (pictured). I'm worried because snails usually lay eggs right above the water line, and the condensation from the tank keeps them moist.... But this will not happen in the position she laid them. I've propped my hood in a manner that might help, but being that far from the surface, will the babies still drop into the water safely? And I'm concerned about them drying up there. I'm trying to avoid removing them to put them in a "paper towel incubator" because it can do alot of damage. What should I do? Will propping the hood (like pictured) be sufficient? If not, what's the best way to remove it without damaging the eggs?

Sidenote: I moved the female into this tank because she had shell damage due to soft water, and I wanted to get her into harder water for her she'll as quickly as possible without further malnutrition while I slowly increased gh, so fish weren't shocked. It's only been a week and it's showing improvement, but I'm curious if this will negativity effect the baby snails (if they hatch), or if water quality - not mother's health, is what effects their development? I also cannot increase water level because I have babies in a hang off nursery that hangs low, and they'd have no air at the top if I add water.
[image: eggs on filter]

[image: hood Angle, Green Arrow pointing under hood where eggs are- top of filter used to prop hood]

Answer (score 2):

The eggs need to stay in a very humid environment to hatch. I had several batches hatch when deposited on the glass above the water line  with a good glass top. 
If there is more than a tiny ( 2% ?) opening in the top , or heat from a light ( even fluorescent) near the eggs they  won't hatch. I don't remember any problem with the young finding the water.

Comment: So, @blacksmith37  I ended up plastic wrapping and taping down all areas where air and water could escape via evaporation from my tank, and it seemed to work because my snails have halfway hatched. It's taken hours and there are between 60-70 hatched plus more popping through. I. I'm so excited. She also laid another clutch in a better location, right above the water line. Fingers crossed

Comment: UPDATE all snails are about a half inch wide and I ended up with a little over 75 from this egg clutch (I stopped counting at 75) and all are doing well! I give them algae tabs and zucchini and calcium supplement for their shells. So Happy with the results... Also, 2nd batch, in more desirable location hatched about 60.

Comment: Great success. They should eat any lettuce; ramshorn snails do but I forgot about mystery snails.